# File gets made but no script in file

Tags: vbscript, readfile, createfile

I have coded the following script out in hopes of the script obtaining information from files in a folder, and summarizing them into a newly made file. When I try to run this script, I get Error (code: 800A1A8, line: 53) "Object required: 'objReadFiles'", but when I insert 'objReadFiles' above line 53, I get an error saying "Type mismatch: 'objReadFiles'" (code: 800A000D). The new file also contains no content.

```
'Create new output file
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("M:\vbscripts\folder\TEST RUN\Summary.txt")


'Read through folder
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("M:\vbscripts\folder\TEST RUN\COMP")
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files 


'Get information and write it in file
For Each objFiles in colFiles
    strName = objFiles.Name
    num = len(strName) - 13
    string_part = left(strName, num)
    datetime = CDATE(objReadFiles.DateLastModified)
    Do While objReadFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        contents = objReadFile.ReadLine
        If Not InStr(contents, "INSTALLED SOFTWARE") > 0 AND InStr(contents, " ") > 0 then
            objFile.Write string_part & "," & datetime & "," & contents & vbCRLF
        End If
    Loop
Next 


'Write result into new output file
objFile.Write "end of file"
```

Comment: Hi Buggy, there is no line 53 in your example. Your Usage of varnames is misleading. The eroror is self explaining an object is required but not set. For beginners `option explicit` which forces you to dim newly introduced variables could be helpful. `For Each objFiles in colFiles` has a plural for a single object - the singular objFile has alreasy a different usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what I did to fix it, but it seemed to work this morning. Just wanted to share my final script:

```
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, colFiles

'Format time stamp for YYYYMMDD_HHMM
strDay = Day(now)
If Len(strDay) < 2 Then
    strDay = "0" & strDay
End If

strMonth = Month(now)
If Len(strMonth) < 2 Then
    strMonth = "0" & strMonth
End If

strYear = Year(now)

strHour = Hour(now)
If Len(strHour) < 2 Then
    strHour = "0" & strHour
End If

strMinute = Minute(now)
If Len(strMinute) < 2 Then
    strMinute = "0" & strMinute
End If

Formated_Stamp = strYear & strMonth & strDay & "_" & strHour & strMinute


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Rename old file
If objFSO.FileExists ("M:\vbscripts\folder\TEST\summary.txt") Then
    objFSO.MoveFile "M:\vbscripts\folder\TEST\summary.txt", "M:\vbscripts\folder\TEST\Old\summary_" & Formated_Stamp & ".txt"
End If

'Read through folder
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("M:\vbscripts\folder\TEST\COMP")
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files 

'Create new output file
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("M:\vbscripts\folder\TEST\summary.txt")

'Get information and write it in file
For Each objFiles in colFiles
    Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFiles)
    Do While objReadFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        contents = objReadFile.ReadLine
        If Not InStr(contents, "INSTALLED SOFTWARE") > 0 AND InStr(contents, " ") > 0 then
            datetime = CDATE(objFiles.DateLastModified)
            strName = objFiles.Name
            num = len(strName) - 13
            string_part = left(strName, num) 
            objFile.Write string_part & ", " & datetime & ", " & contents & vbCRLF
        End If
    Loop
Next 

objFile.Write "End of file."

Wscript.Echo "File has been created."
```

Comment: The first line in your `For` loop didn't exist in your first script: `Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFiles)`

Comment: This time you didn't forget to open the file. Btw  I think `Do While Not objReadFile.AtEndOfStream` is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your varaiables so it's clear what you are doing.

I suspect you are trying to:

- Create an output file
- Process all files in a directory and read each file looking for text
- Write to the output file based on some condition

This code should work a bit better:

```
'Create new output file
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("M:\vbscripts\folder\TEST RUN\Summary.txt")

'Read through folder
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("c:\temp\batches\archive")

'Get information and write it in file
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    num = len(objFile.name) - 13
    string_part = left(objFile.name, num)
    datetime = CDATE(objFile.DateLastModified)

    set objReadStream = objFile.OpenAsTextStream()

    Do While objReadStream.AtEndOfStream <> True
        contents = objReadStream.ReadLine
        If Not InStr(contents, "INSTALLED SOFTWARE") > 0 AND InStr(contents, " ") > 0 then
            objOutputFile.Write string_part & "," & datetime & "," & contents & vbCRLF
        End If
    Loop

    objReadStream.Close()
Next 

objOutputFile.Close()
```